# Figuring out angle from trigonometric function without calculator

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, angle

Consider $\tan^{-1}(2+\sqrt3)$. From this one can figure out that

$$\sin(\theta)=\frac{1+\sqrt3}{2\sqrt2}$$ and

$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{\sqrt3-1}{2\sqrt2}$$

So we now know the sides of the right angle. However, if we try to use the laws of sines or cosines we will run into an obstacle, since we will, again, need to determine the values of trigonometric expressions.

So how can we determine, without using a calculator, the value of $\theta$ in this case?

Comment: How you got denominator as $2\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at $$ \sin ( 2\theta ) = 2\sin (\theta ) \cos(\theta)$$

$$  \sin ( 2 \theta ) = 2\frac{1+\sqrt3}{2\sqrt2}\frac{\sqrt3-1}{2\sqrt2}= 1/2$$

We can find $2\theta $ from the equation

$$\sin ( 2\theta ) =1/2$$

Considering the values for $\sin (\theta )$ and $\cos (\ theta )$ we get $$ 2\theta =5\pi /6$$ Thus  $$ \theta =5\pi /{12}$$

Answer (score 3):

$\arctan(2+\sqrt{3})=75^\circ$. Consider the following configuration:
[image]

If the length of each red segment is $1$, the length of the blue segment is $\sqrt{3}$. It follows that $\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{3}}\right)$ is the orange angle, which is one fourth of $60^\circ$ by symmetry and the relation between angle at the center/angle at the circumference.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the complex number
$$z = \cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta) = \frac{\sqrt{3} - 1 + i(1 + \sqrt{3})}{2\sqrt{2}}.$$
Then
\begin{align*}
z^2 &= \cos(2\theta) + i \sin(2\theta) \\
&= \frac{(\sqrt{3} - 1)^2 - (1 + \sqrt{3})^2 + 2i(\sqrt{3} - 1)(\sqrt{3} + 1)}{8} \\
&= \frac{-4\sqrt{3} + 4i}{8} = \frac{-\sqrt{3} + i}{2} \\
&= \cos\left(\frac{5\pi}{6}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{6}\right).
\end{align*}
From here, we conclude that $z = \cos\left(\frac{5\pi}{12}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{12}\right)$ or $z = \cos\left(-\frac{7\pi}{12}\right) + i\sin\left(-\frac{7\pi}{12}\right)$. Clearly $z$ lies in the first quadrant, so we have
$$z = \cos\left(\frac{5\pi}{12}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{12}\right).$$
In other words, $\theta = \frac{5\pi}{12} + 2\pi k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: There's some $i$s missing in the last several formulas.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Thanks.

Comment: Why squared complex number (quantity or vector) $z$ to show proof. Please elaborate, or state how to ask the same in another post.

Comment: @jiten This was almost 4 years ago, but I squared $z$ because I had a strong feeling that twice the angle would be something more recognisable, so I used De Moivre's Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Law of tangents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_tangents):
$$\frac{a-b}{a+b}=\frac{\tan \frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}}{\tan \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}}.$$
Consider the right angled triangle:

$\hspace{1cm}$[image]

The Law of tangents:
$$\begin{align}\frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}}}{\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}}}&=\frac{\tan \frac{\theta-(90^\circ-\theta)}{2}}{\tan \frac{\theta+(90^\circ-\theta)}{2}} \Rightarrow \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}&=\frac{\tan (\theta-45^\circ)}{1}\Rightarrow \\
\tan(\theta-45^\circ)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \Rightarrow \\
\theta -45^\circ&=30^\circ \Rightarrow \\
\theta &= 75^\circ.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to proceed.  Here is just one.  From a standard isosceles right triangle we know that $\sin 45^0 = \cos 45^0=\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}, and, \tan 45^0=1$.  By considering a equilateral triangle we find $\sin 60^0=\frac {\sqrt 3} 2,  and,  \cos 60^0=\frac 1 2,  so, \tan 60^0=\sqrt 3$.  Now we can also write that $$\tan(A+B)=\frac{\tan A +\tan B}{1-\tan A\tan B}$$.

If we let $A=45^0,  and,  B=30^0 $, then we find that, after some algebra, $\tan 75=2+\sqrt 3$.

Comment: Can you please clarify why do you take these particular values for $A$ and $B$?

Comment: They are the most common and easy to work out that give the right answer.

Comment: In this case we would need to know the value of $\tan(105º)$.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing out the typo - error edited and corrected.

Answer (score 0):

$$2+\sqrt3=\csc2x+\cot2x=\cot x=\tan(90^\circ-x)$$

Here $2x=360^\circ n+30^\circ$ where $n$ is any integer

Use [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values)

Comment: Please tell where in the link your formula is shown. $\csc 2x + \cot 2x= \cot x $, or $1/\sin 2x + \cos 2x/\sin 2x$$ = (1+\cos 2x)/\sin 2x$. How that equals $\cot x=\cos x/ \sin x$. In fact, request a geometric proof too.

Comment: @jiten, See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html